# How to use Leaflet GeoJson Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, leaflet

I'm currently trying to implement a choropleth of NYC with Leaflet.  I'm following along on it's [tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) for doing so, and it was going fine until I reached the "adding interaction" section.  When I try to add the mouseover function, or any other, I can't get `e` to be defined, and my chrome console throws this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setStyle' of undefined` error.

This is the way I've been adding `highlightFeature` as an [option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature) for `onEachFeature`

```
L.geoJson(geoJsonZipCode, {style: style, onEachFeature: highlightFeature}).addTo(map);
```

These are the two functions being called, style works fine, but highlightFeature does not:

```
function style(feature) {
  return {
    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.density),
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
  };
}

function highlightFeature(e) {
  var layer = e.target;

  layer.setStyle({
    weight: 5,
    color: '#666',
    dashArray: '',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
  });

  if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
    layer.bringToFront();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the 'Adding Interaction' section of the tutorial you're following, the `highlightFeature` is attached to a listener for `hover` events: a separate `onEachFeature` function does this. Just follow the technique in the tutorial closely and you'll avoid this issue.

Comment: I added that and it still doesn't work.  Chrome is throwing errors that variables I've used before are now undefined, I'm guessing out of scope. And when I redefine them it throws errors from the leaflet library about undefined variables.

Comment: For some reason deleting the line ```geojson = L.geoJson(statesData, {    style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);``` from the document.ready fixed it.  I don't know why but when I call it in the console it works.